# for what purpose we write e.target.name into the state definition statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I dont have a clear concrete understanding of why we write e.target.name into the state definition statement in react. Who can explain ? thanks in advance.

```
checkboxChange(e) {

let state = {
  ...this.state,
  [e.target.name]: !this.state[e.target.name]
};
...
```

why we write

```
 [e.target.name]: !this.state[e.target.name]
```

in the state

Comment: It is to set a prop of the state as the name of your checkbox. e.target.name is the name (the one you gave) of your component / checkbox.

Comment: This code assumes that a property name in your state object is mapped to the input name in your form fields.

Answer (score 2):

If an input's name is "email" or "password" you can easily set that state key without defining a separate function for each input.

For email and password it would be like:

```
<input name="email" onChange={this._handleChange} />
<input name="password" onChange={this._handleChange} />
```

And the function would be

```
_handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });
}
```

In your case you're setting checkbox values so the same principle applies.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that in your state you have something like this:

```
state = {
  privacyAccepted: false
}
```

Now, you can manage that value with a simple checkbox:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="privacyAccepted"
  ...
/>
```

Once you attach an event handler to this checkbox, you can access the target from the generated event, like:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="privacyAccepted"
  onChange={ this.handlePrivacy }
/>

handlePrivacy = event => {
  event.target // the checkbox element that emitted this event
}
```

From the target, you can access the checkbox properties, like the name, with:

```
handlePrivacy = event => {
  event.target.name // "privacyAccepted"
}
```

Being able to do this, you can then have a generic `onChange` event handler and use the `event.target.name` to access properties in the `state` that have the same name as your inputs:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="privacyAccepted"
  onChange={ this.handleChange }
/>

handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value // ... or what you want here
  })
}
```

This `[...]` syntax to access an object property to set a value is called `computed property` and it is provided by ES6.